# how to scrape sites that is using template engine?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, scrapy

I am trying to scrape a site with `scrapy` and `selenium`.
At first I saw the result of `[ {{ certificant.FirstName }} {{ certificant.LastName }} ]`

So I thought maybe it's because the page is still loading so I added a `WebDriverWait` for an button to show before extracting data but I still get the same result.

I do believe the result I got is from template engine do make things dynamic but if so, what should I do to make the scrape to actually work with this?

This is something I have at the moment

```
import scrapy

from scrapy import Request

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By



class PjFx110Spider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "pj_fx110"

    ROOT_URL = 'https://aplanner.ca'

    start_urls = [
        ROOT_URL
    ]

    def __init__(self):
        options = Options()
#         options.add_argument("--headless")
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome('./chromedriver', options=options)

    def start_requests(self):
        for url in self.start_urls:
            yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse)


    def parse(self, response):
        self.driver.get(response.url)
        WebDriverWait(self.driver, 3600).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'btnShowResults')))

        lists = response.css('.list-group')
        name = lists.xpath('//*[@id="FPlist"]/div/ul[1]/li/span[1]/text()').extract()
        print(name, '---------lists----------')
```

Thank you so much for any suggestions and advices.

Comment: You see those templating tags because the info is not fully rendered in page. Use Waits in selenium, or Expected Conditions (until element is clickable or so). Or better, use a different scraping method.

Comment: @platipus_on_fire_333 I did then try `element_to_be_clickable` which somehow gives infinite page loads not sure why.  Then I tried one that's not best practice `time.sleep(120)` which page loads for two minutes.  Since I have `headless` off, I can see the content are actually loaded before goes to get the `xpath` but still only seeing `[{{}}]` the template engine thing only.

Comment: @platipus_on_fire_333 by different scraping method, can you give an example or direction?

Comment: what are you trying to achieve, what information are you trying to scrape?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will assume you want to obtain the full list of planners (you did not confirm this). You are asking for an alternative, here it is (quite far from what you initially planned, I imagine):

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
headers = {
'authority': 'aplanner.ca',
'path': '/WebServices/AptifyToolsServices.asmx/GetAll',
'scheme': 'https',
'accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9',
'content-length': '0',
'content-type': 'application/json;charset=utf-8',
'cookie': 'ASP.NET_SessionId=345345345345',
'origin': 'https://aplanner',
'referer': 'https://aplanner/findaplanner',
'sec-ch-ua': '"Chromium";v="103", ".Not/A)Brand";v="99"',
'sec-fetch-dest': 'empty',
'sec-fetch-mode': 'cors',
'sec-fetch-site': 'same-origin',
'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/103.0.5060.53 Safari/537.36 x-requested-with: XMLHttpRequest'
}
r = requests.post('https://aplanner.ca/WebServices/AptifyToolsServices.asmx/GetAll', headers=headers)
df = pd.read_json(r.json()['d'])
df.to_csv('aplanner.csv')
print(df.head())
```

This will return a csv file, and a dataframe head, displaying the format of the csv.file, in a minute or so.
If using a Jupyter notebook, you may need to run it with

```
jupyter notebook --NotebookApp.iopub_data_rate_limit=1.0e10
```

Comment: Just wondering, if I still want to use the `scrapy` way, any idea how else I can try?

Comment: You need to make sure the page (and the view) is fully loaded, before extracting the info. However, this isn;t really a job for scrapy.